# I am trying to deploy a model using streamlit

Tags: deployment, conv-neural-network, streamlit

I am working on a CNN model to classify Indian Dance Forms. Other parts of the code have run without any errors, but when I try to deploy it using Streamlit I am getting the following error.

```
streamlit run "C:\Users\Sireesha Kuchimanchi\danceforms.py"
```

Usage: streamlit run [OPTIONS] TARGET [ARGS]...

Error: Invalid value: File does not exist: C:\Users\Sireesha Kuchimanchi\danceforms.py

I have written the complete code in the jupyter notebook and ran the streamlit command in the anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal, navigate to **Sireesha Kuchimanchi** directory then **streamlit run danceforms.py**

By the way it is a good practise to write long directory names with **_**

e,g **Sireesha_Kuchimanchi**.

Now apply the below method in your command line:

```py
cd Sireesha Kuchimanchi
```

if ***cd Sireesha Kuchimanchi*** throws an error then you will have to rename your directory to **Sireesha_Kuchimanchi** and after that try.

```py
cd Sireesha_Kuchimanchi
```

Now you can run your python script with;

```py
streamlit run danceforms.py
```